# How to implement monadic parsing?

Tags: scala, parsing, monads

I'm stuck on understanding how Monad works. I'm writing a Parser by using Grammar S->aSb. Input is  "a^n b^n for n>=0", e.g "aabb"; Return value for this Parser is a Boolean Value.

Previously by using temporary variables for this Grammar. Now I want to implement this parser by using Monad instead of temporary Variables. But i tried many times und still stuck on this problem.

```scala
object Parser {
  case class Parser[+A](parse: List[Char] => Option[(A, List[Char])]) {
    def accepts(l: List[Char]): Boolean
    // If List[Char] is empty after parsing it was successful
    = parse(l).map(_._2.isEmpty).getOrElse(false)

    // Not sure that this exactly does
    def flatMap[B](f: A => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = Parser {
      input => parse(input).flatMap { case (x, midput) => f(x).parse(midput) }
    }

    // a.map( i => i + 1) parses using Parser a and applies function i+1
    def map[B](f: A => B): Parser[B] = Parser {
      input => parse(input) match {
        case Some((t, remains)) => Some((f(t), remains))
        case _ => None
      }
    }

    // a.orElse(b) tries to use Parser a first
    // If a returns None it tries Parser b
    // If b also returns None all rules are exhausted
    def orElse[B](that: Parser[B]): Parser[Either[A, B]] = Parser {
      input => parse(input) match {
        case Some((p, remains)) => Some((Left(p), remains))
        case None => that.parse(input) match {
          case Some((p, remains)) => Some((Right(p), remains))
          case None => None
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Not sure if this is correct
  def unit[T](x: T): Parser[T] = Parser {
    _ => Some((x, List()))
  }

  // Consumes c if possible
  def char(c: Char): Parser[Unit] = Parser {
    case x :: rest if c == x => Some(((), rest))
    case _ => None
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val S: Parser[Int]
    = char('a').flatMap { _ =>
      S.flatMap { i =>
        char('b').map { _ =>
          i + 1
        }
      }
    }.orElse(unit(0)).map(_.merge)

    S.accepts("".toList) // true
    S.accepts("aaabbb".toList) // true
    S.accepts("aaa".toList) // false
    S.accepts("bbbaaa".toList) // false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when we say "monadic parsing", we mean making `Parser` a monad. We write

```
class Parser[+A] { ... }
```

A `Parser[A]` takes input and returns the parsed `A`, or maybe it fails, or maybe there will be some input left over. Let's keep it really simple: a `Parser[A]` takes a `List[Char]`, and `Option`ally returns an `A` and the remaining `List[Char]`.

```
case class Parser[+A](parse: List[Char] => Option[(A, List[Char])]) {
  def accepts(l: List[Char]): Boolean
    = parse(l).map(_._2.isEmpty).getOrElse(false)
  // do not bother with the List('#') stuff
}
```

You build up a `Parser` by using combinators. `a.flatMap(b)` is a parser that matches `a` followed by `b`

```
// case class Parser[+A](...) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = Parser { input =>
    parse(input).flatMap { case (x, midput) => f(x).parse(midput) }
  }
// }
```

and `Parser.unit(x)` returns `x` without consuming any input, which is why `Monad` is important. You should also have `map`, which alters the returned value without changing what's matched. You also need a combinator for alternation. I'll leave those for you to implement.

```
object Parser {
    def unit[T](x: T): Parser[T] = ???
}
// case class Parser[+A](...) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Parser[B] = ???

    // left-biased greedy: if this parser succeeds (produces Some) then
    // that parser is never tried (i.e. no backtracking)
    // replacing Option with Seq is the easiest way to get backtracking
    // but we don't need it to define S
    def orElse[B](that: Parser[B]): Parser[Either[A, B]] = ???
// }
```

You also want some basic `Parser`s to build more complicated ones from. `Parser.char(x)` matches the single char `x` and returns nothing useful.

```
// object Parser {
  def char(c: Char): Parser[Unit] = Parser {
    case x :: rest if c == x => Some(((), rest))
    case _ => None
  }
// }
```

Then you can define `S` in a pretty natural manner. You can even make the parser return an `Int` for how many `a`s/how many `b`s were matched:

```
lazy val S: Parser[Int]
  = (for { _ <- Parser.char('a')
           i <- S
           _ <- Parser.char('b')
         } yield (i + 1)).orElse(Parser.unit(0)).map(_.merge)
// i.e
lazy val S: Parser[Int]
  = Parser.char('a').flatMap { _ =>
      S.flatMap { i =>
        Parser.char('b').map { _ =>
          i + 1
        }
      }
    }.orElse(Parser.unit(0)).map(_.merge)

S.accepts("".toList) // true
S.accepts("aaabbb".toList) // true
S.accepts("aaa".toList) // false
S.accepts("bbbaaa".toList) // false
```

You do not have to move the `List[Char]` around in the definition of `S`, because the combinators we've written do that for you, leaving behind only the logic of the grammar itself.

Comment: @Vincent `S` is a parser. It corresponds to your class `AnBn`. I renamed it because of your comments: `S -> aSb; S -> ε`. Instead of writing parsers out of actual code like in your original, parsers are now instead more like data, and functions like `orElse` etc. combine parsers to make new parsers. `orElse` is the combinator for alternation; `a.orElse(b)` is a parser that tries to parse with `a` and falls back to `b`. It roughly corresponds to the `|` you would write in a regular expression (except we don't have backtracking). `orElse` is used to build the final parser `S`.

Comment: When you call `a.flatMap(b).accepts(cs)`, then `a.parse(cs)` is called, and then, if that successfully returned `Some(a, cs2)`, then `b(a).parse(cs2)` is called. The `flatMap`s don't execute anything; they build a `Parser`, which is just a function object. Execution only occurs with `accepts` or `parse`. You can't write something like `case object AnBn { def accepts(l: List[Char]) = ??? }` with `flatMap`, unless you want `def accepts(l: List[Char]) = { val S = ??? /* what I wrote */; S.accepts(l) }`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It works in the REPL but in an actual `.scala` file it appears to need `lazy`.